# How can I display a dialog from an Android broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Ideally, I do not want to start an activity to do this. When the WiFi connection is lost, my app needs to close because this is a fatal error for us. I want to display an error message and have the user press an Ok button and then exit the app. What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, only activities can display dialogs. If so, and if your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered by an activity via `registerReceiver()`, you're set -- just use that activity. If, however, your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, I think you will have no choice but to do something else.

For example, you could send an ordered broadcast `Intent`. Your currently-running activity -- if any -- would have a high-priority `BroadcastReceiver` for that `Intent`, then can pop a dialog when it receives the broadcast. If, however, none of your activities are on screen, you could have a manifest-registered low-priority `BroadcastReceiver` pick up the broadcast, if you wanted to display a `Notification` or something. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) that covers a bit more about this pattern.

Comment: I am registering the receiver via registerReceiver() but when I try to display the dialog from onReceive method, it does not show up. What could be the problem?

Comment: @smitten: Not sure what `Context` you are using for the dialog -- make sure it is the `Activity`. Otherwise, AFAIK, that should work just fine.

Comment: If using intent  from broadcast receiver add : intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);