# Showing an AlertDialog from Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

How do i show an AlertDialog from receiver class. My receiver class receives by time of my Alarm using `AlarmManager`. And, my alertdialog can show if my application is not opened also.

How can i achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you place any buttons in your alertdialog. Or just showing some details only.

Comment: Hi, again you thanks for your response. I just shows some details to alertdialog. Not any buttons.

Comment: You can, check out this stackoverflow thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835160/how-can-i-display-a-dialog-from-an-android-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do like this. Just start one activity class from your receiver using `Intent` and in that activity class just use the code from this [Blog](http://sherifandroid.blogspot.in/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html)

Change that class with whatever you needs for AlertDialog. This will display the when your application closed also. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Praveen the link is not valid

Comment: @AndroidOptimist No its working fine. Check again - http://www.sherif.mobi/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html

Comment: @Praveen ya now its working, but just before the page shown error. Sorry and thanks

Comment: @AndroidOptimist Its okay. No problem

Comment: @Praveen i would like to hide the main activity and when i trigger the receiver i would like my dialog to be shown. How to achieve this?

Comment: @AndroidOptimist You please simply refer that example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43410/discussion-between-androidoptimist-and-praveen)

Answer (score 2):

There is not possible to create AlertDialog from Broadcast Receiver.
But there is one way to accomplish this task.

1. Create a activity and set the theme as a dialog.
2. OnReceive() method of your Broadcast Receiver start the activity which you had create in 1st step
3. You have to set the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to start the activity from the broadcast receiver.

So you code will looks like below

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, yourDialogActivity.class);
    i .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @Dharmendra thanks for ur ans. Here i would like to hide the main activity and when i trigger the event i would like my dialog to be shown? how can i achieve this?